# JQuery chosen dropdown gets “cut” when placed inside scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good afternoon,

I am using jQuery "chosen" plugin for "select" dropdown. The problem is that dropdown is located in the scrollable area. In this case dropdown items get "cut" by outer div element.
I created a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/olegbevz/083z9ctL/1

```
<div class="dialog" style="height: 100px;">
  <div style="height:100px; overflow-y:auto">
        <select id="select" style="width: 205px;">
                <option>Some Value</option>
                <option>Some Value</option>
                <option>Some Value</option>
                <option>Some Value</option>
                <option>Some Value</option>
                <option>Some Value</option>
                <option>Some Value</option>
                <option>Some Value</option>
                <option>Some Value</option>
    </select>
  </div>      
</div>

$("#select").chosen({ width: "200px", disable_search: false });
$(".dialog").dialog();
```

If you try to open dropdown on the dialog you can see that it is getting cut.

Is there any solution to this issue?

**Update:** As I have mentioned I need to place select inside the scrollable area, so I can't remove "overflow-y" attribute. After the select tag there can be other controls that does not fit in outer div, that's why scrollbar is required. I improved my example to make it more clear what I want to achieve: [jsfiddle.net/olegbevz/083z9ctL/5](http://jsfiddle.net/olegbevz/083z9ctL/5).

Answer (score 0):

Add new containing div that has zindex set to higher than the upper div, and remove the overflow-y from the upper one

```
 <div style="height:100px;">
  <div style="z-index:1000;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/083z9ctL/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as i have mentioned i need to place select inside the scrollable area, so I can't remove "overflow-y" attribute. After the select tag there can be other controls that does not fit in outer div and that is why scrollbar will be required. I improved my example to make it more clear what do i want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/olegbevz/083z9ctL/5/.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `style=" overflow-y:auto;"` needs to be set to the `<select>` tag, you have set it to `<div>` tag wrongly,

Change your `<select>` tag as,

```
   <select id="stateLicenseSelect" style="width: 205px;" style=" overflow-y:auto;">
```

**Updated Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/083z9ctL/3/

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as i am afraid i need to place select inside the scrollable area, so I can't move "overflow-y" attribute to select tag. After the select tag there can be other controls that does not fit in outer div and that is why scrollbar will be required. I improved my example to make it more clear what do i want to achieve: jsfiddle.net/olegbevz/083z9ctL/5 .